# SQL: Selecting between dates

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables that look like:

```
table A:
ID, target_date, target_ID

table B:
ID, target_ID, begin_date, end_date
```

Table B may have multiple records for the same target_ID but different date ranges.  I am interested in a SQL query that is able to return target_dates that are not within the begin_date and end_date ranges for the given target_ID.

Comment: Can you provide samples of what you've already tried?

Comment: Probably not that important, but you should add a tag for the DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a trick to this.  Look for the ones that match, using a `left join`, and then choose the ones that don't match:

```
select a.*
from tablea a left join
     tableb b
     on a.target_id = b.target_id and
        a.target_date between b.begin_date and b.end_date
where b.target_id is null;
```

You can express this in several different ways.  For instance, `not exists` may also seem natural:

```
select a.*
from tablea a
where not exists (select 1
                  from tableb b
                  where a.target_id = b.target_id and
                        a.target_date between b.begin_date and b.end_date
                 );
```

Note:  I am using `between` for these comparisons as a convenient shorthand (to match the language you use in the question).  Often with dates, explicit use of `<`, `<=`, `>`, or `>=` is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.target_date 
FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B 
     ON (A.target_ID=B.target_ID 
     AND A.target_date>=B.begin_date 
     AND A.target_date<=B.end_date) 
WHERE B.begin_date IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
SELECT target_date FROM A 
   INNER JOIN B 
   ON A.target_ID = B.target_ID
WHERE target_date NOT BETWEEN begin_date AND end_date
```